# JAXB - Create JAVA files instead of .class files in 'xjc'

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

All,

How to create java files(.java files) instead of .class files while firing xjc command?
What is the argument used with xjc to achieve this?

Also,explain why we used -extension and -episode as arguments to xjc?How these arguments are useful?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have something like below:<exec executable="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/xjc.exe" failonerror="true">
   <arg value="-extension"/>    
   <arg value="-d"/>
   <arg value="${finalSrcDir}"/>
   <arg value="-b"/>
   <arg value="naxml.episode"/>
   <arg value="-episode"/>   
   <arg value="report.episode"/>   
   <arg value="-p"/>
   <arg value="com.verifone.isd.viper.eps.pres.messages.reports.data"/>
   <arg value="${reportschemadir}/reportData.xsd"/>
  </exec>

Comment: Are you generating from eclipse? Where is your output path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the following cal, thenl XJC will make `.java` files instead of `.class` files:

```
xjc your_schema.xsd
```